# jBPM 6 - How to hold Task from Rest API

Tags: rest, jboss, jbpm

How can I suspend a Task from Rest API.

I'm using the following code

```
RuntimeEngine engine = sessionBean.getEngine(implementationId);
        TaskService taskService = engine.getTaskService();
        taskService.start(taskId, actorId);
        taskService.complete(taskId, actorId, data);
```

It works fine, now I want to save task Status between start and complete in different moments, but I don't know How to pass the data Map in order to hold the actual State.

```
taskService.suspend(taskId, actorId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the implementation of the Save operation in the jbpm console. 
That's done via saving the output values of the task as far as remember. By the way, suspend is not the right method to call to save the state, because it means a completely different thing. 
You can start looking at here: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-console-ng/blob/master/jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks-forms/jbpm-console-ng-human-tasks-forms-client/src/main/java/org/jbpm/console/ng/ht/forms/client/editors/taskform/FormDisplayPresenter.java

and go down to the actual implementation.

Regards

Comment: Mauricio, thanks for your valuable support. Unfortunately when I use `internalTaskService.addContent(taskId, data);` It tells me that this operation is not supported by Rest API. I've made changes to my process to have a flag that indicates if task is finished or suspended and return to the same task if is suspended.